# Monitor Web Browsing Habits of Networked Users

Tags: freebsd, network-monitoring

I've been tasked with generating dynamic, real-time (or as close to real-time as possible) reports on the web browsing habits of my users.

Basically we need a way of charting the amount of time user X spends on website Y.

The last stop on our network is a FreeBSD box that is currently generating netflow data. I've reviewed some netflow analyzers but none seem to meet our needs.

Any tools or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're worried about what your employees are doing when they should be doing something else, it's a better idea to hold them to expected production than to play big brother and spy on everyone. Multiple studies have shown many workers who screw around on the net during the work day are actually more productive than those who don't. Address the problem (lack of production) not the symptoms.

Comment: I actually agree with you. Unfortunately this project isn't my call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proxy?

Usually this is done by setting up a proxy or filter through which everyone passes traffic through. I've done this with Squid on FreeBSD/Linux, and now we have 8e6 that integrates with our Cisco firewall. If you take the squid route there are tools that can analyze the logfiles (or you can roll your own), while commercial filters have web interfaces for generating reports.

Comment: It's been years since I played with Squid; completely forgot about it. I'll look into that again. But off the top of your head can you think of anything that will analyze my list of netflow logs to produce similar results?